# Add custom errors to req.validationErrors()?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using express validation to validate my data input. It's great, but some data is not practical to check using validation (forexample if to check if a facebook token is valid)

Is there some way to do this with validation that I can't think of or can I at least somehow manually add errors by passing an object or such?

```
auth = (req, res, next) => {
    //some setup:
    res.locals.errors = [];
    passport.authenticate('facebook-token', (err, user, info) => {
        //this is where I would like to either validate with a custom validation or add this manually to whereever validationErrors get's it's values.
        if(err && err.message === "Failed to fetch user profile"){
            res.locals.errors.push({
                param: 'access_token',
                msg: 'Invalid access token',
                value: req.query.access_token
            });
        }

    })(req, res, next);
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hit the same problem. I wanted to somehow add errors to the array generated by express-validator so that they are shown when you call `req.validationErrors()`.

The validation I wanted however was more than just a quick type check on a specific param or header - I wanted to check multiple fields at once and shove any failed errors into the standard validationErrors array.

I achieved this by adding a 'customValidator' using [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator#customvalidators). My custom validator ***will always return false***

I injected my custom validator like this:

```
app.use(expressValidator({
 customValidators: {
    myCustomFunc: function(value) {
       return false;
    }
 }
}));
```

Now I only call this custom validator if my custom logic fails - this has the effect of setting an error in the validationErrors array. Since express-validator requires you to pass a valid param/header I decided to create my own dummy one and then call the custom validator on that field knowing that it will return false. I am essentially using it as a flag:

```
// code to check for custom logic - needs reqeust object
// in this simple example I check whether field2 is set if
// we have field1
function isValidRequest(req, cb){

  if(req.headers.myField1 && !req.headers.myField2){
    // create dummy header field
    req.headers.myDummyHeader = false;
    // now call customValidator, pass it our new dummy header  
    req.checkHeaders("myDummyHeader", 
   "Invalid request, myField1 and myField2 should both be set").myCustomFunc();
  }

cb()
}

...

// (later) get the express validation errors 
// you'll see that our custom error message is included
var errors = req.validationErrors();
console.log(errors);
```